# How can I modify android's native camera application with my own UI?

Tags: android, android-camera

The custom camera application that I have implemented at the moment for an application gives really bad picture quality and I don't want to use Camera intent to take picture but want a standalone application that has its own camera rather than navigating to camera application.

Is it possible to modify the native camera application (since it is open source) to include my own custom user interface for taking picture and so on as shown in the example below?

[image]

If you have done something like this then please let me know.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes, at least in theory. Cleaning up any references inside that code base to things not in the Android SDK may be unpleasant.

Comment: In theory..there are are apps like this screenshot is from whtatsapp; that they have implemented it but may be it takes really much effort.

Comment: The problem with the AOSP apps is that they are not really designed to be built by the Android SDK -- they are designed to be built as part of the firmware. If you wanted to start with a camera app and edit from there, you may be better served by starting with Focal. Or, if you want to improve the core logic that you already have, my [CWAC-Camera](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) library is trying to make mid-range camera logic easier to add into apps. It's not designed for high-end camera apps, though.

Comment: I downloaded the library but getting too many errors. Do you have a demo app somewhere ?

Comment: Three demo apps are in the library's repo (e.g., `demo/`).

Comment: Thanks . i checked the demo and the quality is same as the custom camera app that i have with me. But thank you for your effort.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can take a look at this [example](http://android-er.blogspot.ro/2010/12/implement-takepicture-function-of.html) and costumize your UI

Comment: If you actually read that blog post, it has nothing to do with modifying the native camera application. Moreover, it is from 2010, which means that even if it *did* have to do with modifying the native camera application, it would be out of date. Finally, answers should actually answer the question at least *somewhat*, even if you cite some third-party source for all of the details.

Comment: It is an example the main idea is to play with SourfaceView and add additional view elements. The year is not relevand dear @CommonsWare... I can make the above image in max 1h with that example as a base to start this....

Comment: I have clearly said that I have already implemented the custom camera in my application which is the same thing that the blog is saying.